# diffForHumans for regular dates in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So on my website, I want to be able to tell when a job is due.

I can print the date just fine,

```
<p>Due in: {{ $active_commission->estimated_date }}</p>
```

will give me "Due in: 2017-04-28" for example.

Now, that's cool and all, but I would rather it say something like: "8 days from now".

Elsewhere on my site, I use diffForHumans for a similar effect:

```
<p>Created:{{ $quotes->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</p>
```

will give me something like "Created: 3 days ago."

Which is great. However, diffForHumans seems to only work on timestamps, whereas I'm using a date.

What could I use to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the date to create a Carbon instance:

```
{{ Carbon::parse($active_commission->estimated_date)->diffForHumans() }}
```

But a better way is to add `estimated_date` to the `$dates` property so Eloquent would automatically make it a Carbon instance. In this case, you'll be able to do this:

```
{{ $active_commission->estimated_date->diffForHumans() }}
```